# Android Studio, Missing Gradle settings

Tags: android

Dont have Gradle settings in Android Studio.

I should get something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNjQ.jpg

But i got something like this.[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaigU.png)

Always i run gradle i got some error and Now i got error with end header. So i changed like before gradle 6.1.1 version from all to bin and it worked So i dont know where problem is

Answer (score 0):

Check under Build Tools (in the left sidebar) under Build, Execution, Deployment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).